# Why aren't my anchor points snapping to guidelines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, cs3

I've been using Photoshop CS3 for quite some time in my work, but this one has really bugged me. When I have created a vector shape with the Pen tool, as I want to move those anchor points precisely to a specific point I sometimes need to snap it using some guidelines. But the anchor points don't seem to snap to any guides or even to edges of my other layered images.

**How do I make the anchor point snap to guidelines?**

Comment: Top menu: **View > Snap to > Guides**.

Comment: It's currently set to snap to all. Still doesn't work. I would have to zoom in at max but it still wouldn't snap to the guide.

Comment: Try unchecking them all, check `Guides` and try again.

Comment: It makes sense. If guides are the only one that anything snaps on to. It won't get confused which one it should snap to. I'll go ahead and try it and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason. it worked. checked none. then checked all back again. for some reason this time it snapped to a point of 2 guidelines crossing each other. Cool! i wonder if it's a memory thing before but I do have 4gb ram. gee. Anyway it worked. Thanks @Joonas. Cheers!

Comment: Perfect, by removing all the checks and just by enabling them back did it. Bug in my CS3? Thanks! @Joonas, how do I make your select yours as my chosen answer? Your post is not posted as an answer that I can rate.

Comment: Yea it's a bug that happens sometimes. I just edited the already selected answer since he had already said most of what was needed. He didn't exactly say anything anout unchecking the other snapping options so I just made sure that it's clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still can't choose your answer as the best.

Comment: I know, it's ok. I tend to to comment a lot instead of commenting. I keep making that bed, so I might as well lie on it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uncheck all of the other snapping options and check just the one you need.

From the top menu:  **View » Snap to** » **Guides**.
[image]

Comment: Ah, good suggestion. I will try that and get back to you on that. thanks.

Comment: Actually your answer did it too. By removing all the checks and just checking only guides. But who answered first?

Comment: This doesn't work on CS6. In fact, there's no way to snap anchor points to anything but another anchor point, as I read. It only snaps to pixel level. Would that be conflicting with the other snaps?